# Dropbox-like software that doesn't sync

Tags: windows, file-management, windows-10

I'm looking for a software that's similar to Dropbox's client that only syncs with one computer (or just doesn't sync at all). Basically, I can self-host or buy a service such as SFTP, WebDAV, etc and then:

- Manage a folder or drive through Windows Explorer for easy access and quick file operations
- I don't have to login to it every time (it just mounts, I don't have to start a client, login, navigate to the correct folders, etc).
- I don't have to let stuff sync to my 3 computers due to size constraints and the hassle of letting huge things sync.

I'm interested regardless of if it's free or not.

Comment: Some Dropbox competitors have the ability to show files in the cloud without downloading them. OneDrive had that, for example, but it was removed in W10 for some reason.

Comment: Would [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) work?

Comment: Seems to be about the same as FTP, no? I also found [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/support/) which I think I've seen before but it just wasn't as feature complete as the last time I saw it. It's a little pricey but I think it'll be worth my money just to be able to stop worrying about file management.

Comment: So, you are looking for FTP (or WebDAV) hosting, right? Or are you looking for software?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I rephrased the question in relation to an edit someone made. I meant that I'm looking for software like Dropbox's _client_ not their service (like I wrongly had said before).

Comment: So you want something that "mounts" a remote folder to a drive letter in your Windows Explorer, right? Actually I wrote [a tool that does this for remote folders via the CMIS protocol](https://github.com/aegif/CmisDrive) but it still has many bugs haha

Answer (score 2):

[DokanCloudFS](https://github.com/viciousviper/DokanCloudFS) shows in your Windows Explorer the content of a remote folder you host at your favorite provider (MEGA, Google Drive, OneDrive and [many others](https://github.com/viciousviper/CloudFS#supported-cloud-storage-services) are supported). Of course your files are also usable and editable via any other Windows program.

Free and open source.

[image: DokanCloudFS screenshot]

As a bonus, files are encrypted with the password of your choice, so the cloud provider can't spy on your files.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an FTP server, you might want to try [FtpUse](http://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html).

It is a command line tool that makes a remote FTP folder appear inside your filesystem. Run the command, then you can browse your files in Windows Explorer.

[image: FtpUse demo]

Free but not open source.

Answer (score 0):

GroupDrive does everything you are asking for.  There's a client that maps a drive letter and there's also a browser client.  It's about 10 bucks per user.  [www.groupdrive.com](http://www.groupdrive.com)